# Style in the body tag not affect the Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, webview, fonts

I'm getting an html code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head> 
  <body style="font-family:Open Sans">    
    <p><strong> Dumy /strong></p>
    <p>
      Dumyp
    </p>
    <p>
      Dumyp2
    </p>
    <p>
      Dumyp3
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I'm setting this html data to my webView like this

```
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setLongClickable(false);
webView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> true);
webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadData(productsResultObject.getProductDetail(), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
webView.setHorizontalScrollbarOverlay(false);
```

and font is not changing on my webview.

Comment: have you import the font?

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but you have to add the link for the type of font you want , you can use other properties. to use the font copy the link for the font from google font